# Make a analyze api call using the JEST

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch-jest

I have a very simple requirement, I need to get the analyzed text of my search term based on the default analyzer set for my index.

I am using the analyze API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-analyze.html to get the desired tokens.

I am able to get it using `curl` request.

I am using 2.X version of ES and **JEST** library. I looked into the various files of **JEST** library but couldn't find support for making the **Analyze** API call.